# HTML dom insertRow()

Tags: dom

I run into a problem while tring to add new row to Table.
The problem is the new row is added into  blcok rather than  block.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(1);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
    cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
}
```

```css
table{
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
   <thead>
        <tr>
         <th>Product</th>
         <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
   </thead>

   <tbody>
         //new row is supposed to add into here.
   <tbody>
</table>
<br>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wanted to add new row to `tbody`, so select tbody first using `getElementsByTagName("tbody")` on . Also use `insertRow(0)` instead of `insertRow(1)`

```js
function myFunction() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName('tbody');
    console.log(tbody)
    var row = tbody[0].insertRow(0);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
    cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
}
```

```css
table{
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
   <thead>
        <tr>
         <th>Product</th>
         <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
   </thead>

   <tbody>
         //new row is supposed to add into here.
   <tbody>
</table>
<br>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```